# Difference between Index column and simple column in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, custom-list, indexed-column

Difference between Index column and simple column in SharePoint?

What is the need of creating index column ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An indexed column in SharePoint makes sense to improve performance.
If your list contains a lot (~1000s) of records, and you often query (filter or sort) by a given column, you can *index* that column. That way, when displaying a filtered/sorted view (based on this column), SharePoint does not have to loop throuh all the items to decide which ones to display (first): thanks to the index it can quickly get the elements it needs.

A lot of articles on the Web can be found, that discuss the topic deeply:

- Official doc: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59#__creating_sharepoint_indexed
- How it works Under the Hood: https://web.archive.org/web/20161031123124/http://apmblog.dynatrace.com:80/2009/01/28/sharepoint-list-performance-how-list-column-indices-really-work-under-the-hood/
- Some tips: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/12/16/things-to-note-about-indexed-columns-in-sharepoint/
- Another one on SE: [Should i index all columns in a list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52319/should-i-index-all-columns-in-a-list)

As you can see, it's only a matter of googling something like "sharepoint indexed column"...

Comment: Another reason for indexing a column, other than just performance is being able to query that column in a list that has a large number of items that exceed the View Threshold. If you try and query said list and just return a smaller number of results (Even 1), you'll get an error if you query a column that isn't indexed