# Having multiple indices may freeze entire DB?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, content-database, performance, list-view-threshold

[Here is the post for reference on recommendation to create indices in list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52319/should-i-index-all-columns-in-a-list).

It makes sense to create minimum indices. I've a case so I needed SharePoint community's help in understanding if in worst case multiple indices may freeze entire database or just tables for this site collection?

I've a list with 35K+ items. It already have 10 indices configured while there is need to create more. Actually 20 in total. I understand that having multiple indices may result in expensive queries so will there be situation when database gets freeze? Further, how this many indices impact other site collections since multiple site collections share same content DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had contacted Microsoft and below are recommendations:

1. Ensure list size does not grow beyond threshold
2. If it has to, kindly ensure to divide data logically by creating multiple folders i.e. diving data hierarchically
3. Further, each Index in itself is a table and is expensive. I didn't get any input of how many indices are appropriate but the minimum is better.

Having multiple indices may freeze entire DB? - **No**. At max the query many take a lot time to execute thus for other users who have Site Collection in same database, the site will become slow until query executes.